# What is the name of the technique or algorithm to write or read xml files from DataSets

Tags: xml, dataset

```
'>>> create a dataset, datatable to hold file content, password
    Dim DsImg As New DataSet
    Dim Dt As New DataTable("Images")
    Dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("sysid", System.Type.GetType("System.String")))
    Dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("filename", System.Type.GetType("System.String")))
    Dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("image", System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]")))
    Dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("filetag", System.Type.GetType("System.String")))
    DsImg.Tables.Add(Dt)

    '>>> convert the file to binary
    Dim Fs As New System.IO.FileStream(TxtFileName.Text, System.IO.FileMode.Open)
    Dim bn As New System.IO.BinaryReader(Fs)

    '>>> save the details in dataset, tables

    Dim Dr As DataRow
    Dr = DsImg.Tables("images").NewRow
    Dr("sysid") = Now.ToString
    Dr("filename") = TxtFileName.Text
    Dr("image") = bn.ReadBytes(Int(bn.BaseStream.Length))
    Dr("filetag") = StrEncrypt(TxtPassword.Text)
    DsImg.Tables("images").Rows.Add(Dr)

    '>>> write xml file from dataset with binary content
    DsImg.WriteXml(TxtFileName.Text & ".sp2p")
```

In this code, we are writing XML file from DataSets to encrypt the content of file.

**My question is, what is the name of this technique or algorithm ?**

Comment: `Serialization` is the act of converting the `DataSet` into `XML`.

Comment: you're serializing object into xml